# Tkinter quiero avanzar con la tecla intro una vez ingresado el dato entre varias entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, entrada

En el ejemplo que esta a continuación quiero ingresar el dato en cada una de las celdas y al apretar la tecla enter/intro acepte el dato y busque la siguiente.

Le agregaría tambien si se puede poner un orden de entrada a la manera de VisualBasic TabIndex.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
top = Frame(root)
top.pack()

label = Label(top, text='Entrada de Datos continuados con Enter y que salte a la otra casilla')
entry = Entry(top)
entry2 = Entry(top)
entry3 = Entry(top)

label.pack()
entry.pack()
entry2.pack()
entry3.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Al decir: busque en el siguiente, te refieres a que cambie de Entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar `event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()`

Mi Solución:

```
from tkinter import *


def focus_next_window(event):
    event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()

root = Tk()


top = Frame(root)
top.pack()

label = Label(top, text='Entrada de Datos continuados con Enter y que salte a la otra casilla')
entry = Entry(top)

entry2 = Entry(top)
entry3 = Entry(top)

label.pack()
entry.pack()
entry2.pack()
entry3.pack()

root.bind("<Return>", focus_next_window)

root.mainloop()
```