# Tecla INTRO para aceptar entry tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Lo que quiero es que al teclear `INTRO` realice lo mismo que hace el botón **Aceptar**. He seguido la pregunta que se realizó ([Tkinter quiero avanzar con la tecla intro una vez ingresado el dato entre varias entry](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40629/tkinter-quiero-avanzar-con-la-tecla-intro-una-vez-ingresado-el-dato-entre-varias)) pero no obtengo resultado y tampoco obtengo un error para saber que pasa, pienso que quizas la función`def on Enter()` no esta siendo llamada.

He colocado este código para llamar a la tecla **INTRO**:

```
def onEnter(self,event):
    self.sismor_funcion()
    self.entry_1.bind('<Return>', self.sismor_funcion)
```

que está dentro del siguiente código:

```
from tkinter import *
class sismicidad():
    def __init__(self):
        self.vent_sismi = tk.Tk()
        self.vent_sismi.iconbitmap("sismo_ico_1.ico")
        self.vent_sismi.title("SISMICIDAD")
        self.pest_sismor = ttk.Notebook(self.vent_sismi)
        self.pest_sismor.grid(row=0, column = 0)
        self.sismorresistente_1()
        self.perf_suelos()
        self.zona_sismi()
        self.sismor_funcion()
        #self.onEnter()
        self.vent_sismi.mainloop()
#Funciones para ZONAS SISMORRESISTENTE:
    def sismorresistente_1(self):
        ...
#Funcion de CERRAR:
    ...
#Funciones para PERFILES DE SUELOS:
    def perf_suelos(self):
        self.pest_1 = ttk.Frame(self.pest_sismor)
        self.pest_sismor.add(self.pest_1, text = "Perfiles de suelos")
        self.eti_fra_11 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.pest_1, text="Perfiles de suelos")
        self.eti_fra_11.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        ...
        self.eti_lab_11 = ttk.Label(self.eti_fra_11)
        self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=80, pady=10)
        ...
        self.entry_1 = ttk.Entry(self.eti_fra_11, textvariable = self.vel_corte)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        #Falta poner Boton: CALCULAR
        self.boton_aceptar = ttk.Button(self.eti_fra_11, text ="Aceptar", command = self.sismor_funcion)
        self.boton_aceptar.grid(row=2,column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    #Mostrar Tabla de Vs:
    def abrir_vs(self):
        ...
    #Funciones para PERFILES DE SUELOS:
    def sismor_funcion(self):

        self.x1=self.entry_1.get()
        ...
        while True:
            if self.x1 > 1500:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S0: Roca Dura.", font = "helvetica 12", foreground= "blue")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            elif self.x1 > 500 and self.x1 <= 1500:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S1: Roca y Suelos muy rigidos.", font = "helvetica 12", foreground= "blue")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            elif self.x1 > 180 and self.x1 <= 500:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S2: Suelos Intermedios.", font = "helvetica 12", foreground= "blue")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            elif self.x1 > 0 and self.x1 <= 180:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S3: Suelos Blandos.", font = "helvetica 12", foreground= "blue")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            elif self.x1 == 0:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            break

    def onEnter(self,event):
    ...
#Funciones para ZONAS SISMICAS:
    def cerrar_sismicidad(self):    
    ...
aplicacion = sismicidad()
```

No he colocado código que es irrelevante para la pregunta.

Comment: ¿No debería estar lo de `self.entry_1.bind('<Return>', self.sismor_funcion)` en el mismo sitio donde se crea `entry_1` (o sea, en `perf_suelos()`)? El método `onEnter()` sobraría, pues no lo estás llamando nunca que yo vea.

Comment: Al parecer el `self.entry_1.bind('<Return>', self.sismor_funcion)` debería de estar dentro de una función, pero igual voy a probar como me lo recomiendas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `onEnter` jamas será llamada, lo que permitiría que lo sea es el enlace del evento con la callback que se hace mediante `bind`, lo cual haces dentro de la función, por lo que nunca quedan asociadas.

La solución es tan simple como prescindir de la función y realizar la llamada a `bind` tras crear el entry:

```
self.entry_1 = ttk.Entry(self.eti_fra_11, textvariable = self.vel_corte)
self.entry_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
self.entry_1.bind('<Return>', self.sismor_funcion)
```

No obstante, la función (método de instancia en este caso) debe aceptar el evento que causó su llamada como argumento. Para solucionarlo, tienes dos opciones:

- Modificar `sismor_funcion` para que acepte el parámetro:

  ```
  def sismor_funcion(self, event=None):
      # Resto igual
  ```

  o también:

  ```
  def sismor_funcion(self, *args):
      # Resto igual
  ```
- Dejar `sismor_fuction` como está y usar una expresion `lambda` para envolverla y que "consuma" el argumento :

  ```
  self.entry_1.bind('<Return>', lambda event: self.sismor_funcion())
  ```

  o lo mismo pero con una función normal:

  ```
  def on_enter(self, event):
      self.sismor_funcion()

  self.entry_1 = ttk.Entry(self.eti_fra_11, textvariable = self.vel_corte)
  self.entry_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
  self.entry_1.bind('<Return>', self.on_enter)
  ```

Comment: Ok, puedo usar la primera solución, y si quiero colocarla en una función debo de estruturarlas como las opciones 1 o 2... Gracias!!